# How to monitor user actions without server side?

Tags: javascript, analytics, monitoring, client-side, evaluation

Our app is a widget based, for the client-side used mostly JavaScript. For the evaluation purpose information about user behaviour should be gathered. Is it possible to gather information about user click events without accessing server side code?

Comment: How would you collect the data if you don't send it to the server? Or are you talking only about collecting the information and not transmitting it back?

Comment: yes exactly, only collecting data and not  saving it on the server. Google analytics I read can do it, but we look for the alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Your tag has the answer. You can use Google Analytics for tracking client side events.

Have a look at: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: thanks, but we look for the alternative solution as google analytics is not the best way in Germany

Comment: For data rentention laws? Next option is hosting a ready made analytics yourself. But that of course takes resources. Try to reach out to google if they can provide an EU based analytics. I know they can for docs and Gmail for business.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can't create "funnels" on analitycs, so maybe a tool as mixpanel fits better (https://mixpanel.com/).